# How to do 3 thread communication in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a **3 thread communication**. User will input the message for the thread to communicate. The threads suppose to communicate until one of the thread says "Bye". But in my program thread 1 execute only once then gone and the other two threads continue communicate.

The Output of my program looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLW5G.png).

Here is the code:

```java
        import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Conversation {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Chat chat = new Chat();

           new Thread1(chat).start();
           new Thread2(chat).start();
           new Thread3(chat).start();
        }
    }



    class Chat {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1,str2,str3;
        int flag = 0;

        public synchronized void getTalk1() throws InterruptedException {
        if (flag==1 ) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.print("User1: ");
        str1 = sc1.nextLine();
        if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            System.out.println("\nUser1 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        flag = 1;
        notifyAll();
    }

        public synchronized void getTalk2() throws InterruptedException {
        if (flag == 0) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.print("User2: ");
        str2 = sc2.nextLine();
        if(str2.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            System.out.println("\nUser2 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        flag = 0;
        notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void getTalk3() throws InterruptedException {
            if (flag == 3) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.print("User3: ");
            str3 = sc3.nextLine();
            if(str3.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                System.out.println("\nUser3 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
                System.exit(0);
            }


            flag = 3;
            notifyAll();
            }



    }






    class Thread1 extends Thread {
    Chat chat;

    public Thread1(Chat chat) {
        this.chat = chat;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                chat.getTalk1();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    class Thread2 extends Thread {
    Chat chat;

    public Thread2(Chat chat) {
        this.chat = chat;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                chat.getTalk2();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    class Thread3 extends Thread {
        Chat chat;

        public Thread3(Chat chat) {
            this.chat = chat;
        }


        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    chat.getTalk3();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: May want to look into the "produce/consumer" pattern

Comment: Produce and consumer pattern is 2 thread communication I think.

Comment: Not necessarily, a producer may have multiple consumers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create 3 separate `Thread` classes for 3 users. You also don't need 3 separate methods for each user. It's hard to read, maintain, and debug.

I wrote a very simple program for you. In your application, `synchronised` is used to wrap the whole method. It's hard to read, and it's unclear why you synchronised the entire method body. In my example, there is a single point where synchronisation is required and it's well defined: when a user wants to say something to the chat.

Have a look.

```
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Chat chat = new Chat();

        chat.registerUser(new User("user1", chat));
        chat.registerUser(new User("user2", chat));
        chat.registerUser(new User("user3", chat));
    }

}

class Chat {

    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private void registerUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
        System.out.format("'%s' connected to the chat.\n", user);
        user.start();
    }

    public void sendMessage(User user) {
        final String reply = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.format("%s: %s\n", user, reply);

        if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            users.forEach(Thread::interrupt);
            System.out.println("The chat is over.");
        } else {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}

class User extends Thread {

    private final String id;
    private final Chat chat;

    public User(String id, Chat chat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.chat = chat;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (chat) {
                    chat.sendMessage(this);
                    chat.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Someone left. I am done as well.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

An example would be

```
'user1' connected to the chat.
'user2' connected to the chat.
'user3' connected to the chat.
hi
user1: hi
hello
user3: hello
what's up?
user2: what's up?
nothing
user3: nothing
what?
user1: what?
bye
user2: bye
The chat is over.
```

To read:

[the producer–consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 *synchronized* methods but each method is used by 1 thread only.

You have misunderstood the role of *synchronized*.

*synchronized* means an object having *synchronized* block does not let two threads to access the code inside the block at the same time.

Therefore, the 3 threads access one shared resource (System.in) without synchronization and the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Chat chat = new Chat();

        new T1(chat).start();
        new T2(chat).start();
        new T3(chat).start();
    }
}

class Chat {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1,str2,str3;
    int flag = 1;

    public synchronized void Person1() throws InterruptedException {
        while(flag==2 || flag==3) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.print("Person 1: ");
        str1 = sc1.nextLine();
        if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            System.out.println("\nPerson 1 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        flag = 2;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void Person2() throws InterruptedException {
        while(flag==1 || flag==3) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.print("Person 2: ");
        str2 = sc2.nextLine();
        if(str2.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            System.out.println("\nPerson 2 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        flag = 3;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void Person3() throws InterruptedException {
        while(flag==1 || flag==2) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.print("Person 3: ");
        str3 = sc3.nextLine();
        if(str3.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            System.out.println("\nPerson 3 has left the chat. Conversation ended.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        flag = 1;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

class T1 extends Thread {
    Chat chat;

    public T1(Chat chat) {
        this.chat = chat;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                chat.Person1();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class T2 extends Thread {
    Chat chat;

    public T2(Chat chat) {
        this.chat = chat;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                chat.Person2();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class T3 extends Thread {
    Chat chat;

    public T3(Chat chat) {
        this.chat = chat;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                chat.Person3();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```